# How can I add a date stamp to a file i am copying?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am able to copy a file using the below line of code, it works great.  I would love it if the destination file name would include the system date when copied.  I have tried many things, but am unable to achieve the goal.  Cab somebody help me out here?

File.Copy("\Computer1\mall\Files\Computer1.cfg", "c:\ComputerFiles\Computer1.cfg", True)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8) class to set the files [CreationTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime?view=netframework-4.8), [LastAccesstime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastaccesstime?view=netframework-4.8), [LastWriteTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastwritetime?view=netframework-4.8).

```
Dim fileLocation As String = "c:\ComputerFiles\Computer1.cfg"

Dim fi As New FileInfo(fileLocation)
fi.CreationTime = DateTime.Now
fi.LastAccessTime = DateTime.Now
fi.LastWriteTime = DateTime.Now
```

Comment: Thank you for your QUICK reply....... I am a little new at this, do i keep the "file.copy" part?

Comment: @JeffreyRoccaforte yes, absolutely keep the `Copy` command. What I have shown above will only change the three date/time values of the file and will not create a copy as you desire

Comment: I see now!  Works like a charm, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Should i be closing out this ticket properly?

Comment: I am new to this site.  If so, i am not aware how to do that.

Comment: @JeffreyRoccaforte [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I just wanted to add another note.........  I just added more, to copy additional files needed.  Everything is working wonderfully!  THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP!